# underscore groupBy iterating the result

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects that I used groupBy to obtain the below result.

```
{ 'Cloud Revenue': 
   [ { sessionName: 'Business Growth',
       channelName: 'Cloud Revenue',
       channelId: '19:8f128db81595434cb91359e5ebb5a58f@thread.tacv2',
       startDate: '2020-04-12',
       endDate: '2020-04-12',
       startTime: '08:00:00.0000000',
       endTime: '08:30:00.0000000' },
     { sessionName: 'Increase Market Value',
       channelName: 'Cloud Revenue',
       startDate: '2020-04-12',
       endDate: '2020-04-12',
       startTime: '06:30:00.0000000',
       endTime: '07:00:00.0000000' } ],
  General:
   [ { sessionName: 'Value Proposition',
       channelName: 'General',
       startDate: '2020-04-12',
       endDate: '2020-04-12',
       startTime: '07:30:00.0000000',
       endTime: '08:00:00.0000000' } ] }
```

Now, I need to enumerate the entities by key. For eg., in the above case I need to extract the top level property names (Cloud Revenue and General) and assign it to a string variable. I tried using foreach, _.map and _.each, nothing is providing me the top level property strings. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj= { 'Cloud Revenue': 
   [ { sessionName: 'Business Growth',
       channelName: 'Cloud Revenue',
       channelId: '19:8f128db81595434cb91359e5ebb5a58f@thread.tacv2',
       startDate: '2020-04-12',
       endDate: '2020-04-12',
       startTime: '08:00:00.0000000',
       endTime: '08:30:00.0000000' },
     { sessionName: 'Increase Market Value',
       channelName: 'Cloud Revenue',
       startDate: '2020-04-12',
       endDate: '2020-04-12',
       startTime: '06:30:00.0000000',
       endTime: '07:00:00.0000000' } ],
   General:
         [ { sessionName: 'Value Proposition',
         channelName: 'General',
        startDate: '2020-04-12',
        endDate: '2020-04-12',
        startTime: '07:30:00.0000000',
         endTime: '08:00:00.0000000' } ] }

for(keys in obj){
   console.log(keys);
}
```